# column ambiguously defined on using offset and fetch first

Tags: sql-server, inner-join, offset

```
SELECT 
    qplt.description,
    qplab.status_code,
    qplab.start_date,
    qplc.start_date,
    qplc.end_date
FROM  
    price_lists_dur qplab,
    PRICE_LISTS_Tbl qplt,
    PRICE_LIST_CHARGES qplc
WHERE 
    qplt.price_list_id = qplab.price_list_id
    AND qplt.price_list_id = qplc.price_list_id
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH FIRST 40 ROWS ONLY
```

The above code returns an error.

But when I remove the last line offset fetch first, it works fine.

Can someone help with the query?

Comment: Please post the error you are receiving.

Comment: are you sure this is sql server? doesn't look valid syntax

Comment: @RichBenner this is perfectly valid t-sql.

Comment: You have no ORDER BY so it is ambiguous. Also, you should start using ANSI-92 style joins, they have been around for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Which SQL version are you using? OFFSET FETCH is a new feature added to SQL 2012

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Use a proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Answer (score 1):

ORDER BY is mandatory to use OFFSET and FETCH clause
So use:

```
SELECT 
  qplt.description,
  qplab.status_code,
  qplab.start_date,
  qplc.start_date,
  qplc.end_date
FROM  price_lists_dur qplab,
  PRICE_LISTS_Tbl qplt,
  PRICE_LIST_CHARGES qplc
WHERE qplt.price_list_id=qplab.price_list_id
AND qplt.price_list_id =qplc.price_list_id
ORDER BY qplab.status_code --(or the column you want)
OFFSET 10 ROWS  FETCH FIRST 40 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

to fix this try to give different aliases to your similar columns, so for example :

```
SELECT 
  qplt.description,
  qplab.status_code,
  qplab.start_date,
  qplc.start_date as qplc_start_date, --notice the alias
  qplc.end_date 
  FROM  
  price_lists_dur qplab,
  PRICE_LISTS_Tbl qplt,
  PRICE_LIST_CHARGES qplc
 WHERE 
  qplt.price_list_id = qplab.price_list_id
  AND qplt.price_list_id = qplc.price_list_id
  OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH FIRST 40 ROWS ONLY
```